# Sorting array with specific condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a JavaScript array with a specific condition. I tried using `array.sort()`, but it didn't work the way I wanted.

I have an array like this:

```js
leftTable = [
    {tableL:"A", tableR:"E"},
    {tableL:"A", tableR:"E"},
    {tableL:"C", tableR:"D"},
    {tableL:"H", tableR:"A"},
    {tableL:"F", tableR:"G"},
    {tableL:"E", tableR:"A"},
];
```

and I want to sort it like this:

```
leftTable = [
    {tableL:"A", tableR:"E"},
    {tableL:"A", tableR:"E"},
    {tableL:"E", tableR:"A"},
    {tableL:"H", tableR:"A"},
    {tableL:"C", tableR:"D"},
    {tableL:"F", tableR:"G"},
];
```

but what I get is this:

```
leftTable = [
    {tableL: "A", tableR: "E"},
    {tableL: "A", tableR: "E"},
    {tableL: "C", tableR: "D"},
    {tableL: "E", tableR: "A"},
    {tableL: "F", tableR: "G"},
    {tableL: "H", tableR: "A"}
]
```

I have already tried several times, but it didn't work. This is one thing I've tried so far:

```
leftTable.sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a.tableL,a.tableR,b.tableL,b.tableR);
    if (a.tableL < b.tableL) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.tableL > b.tableL) {
       return 1;
    } else if (a.tableL == b.tableL) {
        if(a.tableR == b.tableR) return -1; else return 1;
    } else if (a.tableL == b.tableR) {
        if(a.tableR == b.tableL) return -1; else return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

**My sort logic is this:**

If the values are `{"A","E"}` and the next object has the same values, but just the reverse like `{"E","A"}`, I want them to be sorted together. The same goes if one of the values contains at least one of the values from before, eg: `{"H","A"}` or `{"A","K"}`.

But what I get is that the array is just sorted in ascending order as usual.

May I know if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: How do you handle it when your constraints start challanging each other? Like what would the result look like, when you add these three `{"A", "H"}, {"E", "D"}, {"D", "E"}` to your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `Array.prototype.sort` will be sufficient to do what you want, the following would do the thing.

```js
const getSorted = _entries => {
  let sortedEntries = [];
  let entries = [..._entries]; // make a copy so that will don't mutate original (optional)
  
  while (entries.length > 0) {
    let currEntry = entries.shift();
    let matches = entries.reduce((matches, entry) => {
      if (
        entry.includes(currEntry[0]) &&
        entry.includes(currEntry[1])
      ) {
        entries.splice(entries.indexOf(entry), 1); // remove the matched from original
        matches.push({ entry, pref: 0 }); // if it includes both that is more preferred
        return matches;
      }

      if (
        entry.includes(currEntry[0]) ||
        entry.includes(currEntry[1])
      ) {
        entries.splice(entries.indexOf(entry), 1); // remove the matched from original
        matches.push({ entry, pref: 1 }); // if it includes only one that is less preferred
        return matches;
      }
      
      return matches;
    }, [])
    .sort((a,b) => a.pref - b.pref) // sort by preference
    .map(({ entry }) => entry); // we no longer need pref, only need entry 
    
    sortedEntries.push(currEntry);
    sortedEntries.push(...matches);
  }
  
  return sortedEntries;
}

console.log(getSorted([
  ["A", "E"],
  ["A", "E"],
  ["C", "D"],
  ["H", "A"],
  ["F", "G"],
  ["E", "A"]
]))
```

Comment: @miolkookie You're welcome! It's meant to work really really well xP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the objects should be "sorted" before comparing :

```js
var leftTable = [ { tableL: "A", tableR: "E" },
                  { tableL: "A", tableR: "E" },
                  { tableL: "C", tableR: "D" },
                  { tableL: "H", tableR: "A" },
                  { tableL: "F", tableR: "G" },
                  { tableL: "E", tableR: "A" } ];

leftTable.sort(function(a, b) { return [a.tableL, a.tableR].sort().join()
                        .localeCompare([b.tableL, b.tableR].sort().join()); });

console.log( JSON.stringify( leftTable ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```

---

For variable length strings, custom array compare function might be needed instead :

```js
var leftTable = [ { tableL: "A", tableR: "E" },
                  { tableL: "A", tableR: "E" },
                  { tableL: "C", tableR: "D" },
                  { tableL: "H", tableR: "A" },
                  { tableL: "F", tableR: "G" },
                  { tableL: "E", tableR: "A" } ];

leftTable.sort(function(a, b) { 
  a = [a.tableL, a.tableR].sort();
  b = [b.tableL, b.tableR].sort();
  return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]; 
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( leftTable ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```

Comment: hi, im new to programming,so may i know what array compare function that u suggested or mean?

Comment: @miolkookie it is not needed if the string values are the same length as in your example. I mean function that compares two arrays and returns -1, 0, or 1. I added example that works with variable length strings.